# Filter rows with earlier date than a row specified by another variable

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, slice

I would like to filter all Med = 0 (grouped by ID) only if Med 0 occurs at a Date earlier than the Date for Med =1. How can this be done using dplyr, base r, or other packages.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
              ID  Med  date        
               1  0     2006-01-01 
               1  0     2006-02-02 
               1  1     2006-06-02 
               1  0     2006-08-02 
               1  2     2007-12-01
               2  0     2003-01-01 
               2  1     2003-02-02 
               2  3     2003-06-02 
               2  0     2003-08-02 
               2  8     2007-12-01 
               3  1     2007-04-20 
               ",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can `group_by` `ID`, `arrange` by `date` and select the rows before `Med == 1`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   arrange(date) %>%
   filter(cumsum(Med == 1) == 0 & Med == 0)


#     ID   Med date      
#  <int> <int> <chr>     
#1     1     0 2006-01-01
#2     1     0 2006-02-02
#3     2     0 2003-01-01
```